# Google Apps Script isn't updating a formula in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will create a formula and update said formula in a cell. However when I run the script, the formula isn't pasted into the cell and doesn't show any error when the code is ran.

```
function Update3MA() {

//Getting the spreadsheet and the 3MA avergage page to paste into
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("3MA");

//get previous three months
var date = new Date();
var mt = date.getMonth();
var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JULY", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

var currentM = months[mt-1];
var prevMonth1 = months[mt-2]; 
var prevMonth2 = months[mt-3];

Logger.log(currentM); 
Logger.log(prevMonth1);
Logger.log(prevMonth2);

var threeMonthAVG = "=IFERROR("+currentM+"!H3+"+prevMonth1+"!H3+"+prevMonth2+"!H3)/3";
console.log(threeMonthAVG);

const loopTime = 13;

for (let i = 3; i < loopTime; i++) {
  var pasteCV = pasteSheet.getRange(i, 3,);
  let pasteCVFormula = "=IFERROR("+currentM+"!H"+i+"+"+prevMonth1+"!H"+i+"+"+prevMonth2+"!H"+i+")/3";
  console.log(pasteCVFormula);
  pasteCV.setFormula(pasteCVFormula);
 }
}
```

Comment: Array of current month and previous two `[...Array.from(new Array(3).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - x)), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM").toUpperCase())]`

Comment: About `Google Apps Script isn't updating a formula in a cell`, I think that in your script, when your script is run, the formulas are put into the cells "C3:C12". So, I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: `Google Apps Script isn't updating a formula in a cell` I think there might be some general uncertainty about what, EXACTLY, is your problem. Is it that a formula is NOT being inserted, it is that it is insetrted but into the wrong cell, is that the wrong formula is inserted, etc. `pasteCVFormula` what is the value of this variable?

Comment: @Tedinoz The formula isn't being inserted into the cell

Comment: Did you check the execution log for any errors?  Note that if the month was January `mt = 0` and `month[mt-1]` is undefined

Comment: @LewisP use `pasteCV.setValue()` for check if the formula is really added on the desired cell(s). It might be an error with the formula or you're not setting the formula in the correct cell(s). [edit] your question with the result of `pasteCVFormula`.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Please make sure that you have a sheet named "3MA". (no leading or trailing spaces).

Comment: The code was working fine, I just somehow hid the column C and was looking at column D to see if the code was working. This was an oversight on my part and didn’t realise till after this post. 

Thanks for the help though guys